# Does Mobile Safari clean the DOM Application Cache - and when?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, manifest

We're doing a web app using the DOMApplicationCache / cache manifest, and I'm wondering if Mobile Safari at any point will clean/clear the DOMApplicationCache for my project (eg. if the website is not visited in a certain amount of time).

I'm also told, that saving the web app to the home screen will sandbox its application cache, effectively avoiding any time constraints there might be on the DOMApplicationCache in "normal" Mobile Safari.

So do anybody know what the current situation is on this? Or would you maybe be able to point me to a relevant resource?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, knowing how this actually behaves in Android devices would be a plus, although I expect that to be a very dark jungle with no definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like it should be clearing the cache automatically, from what I can read in Apple's document about storing web content on the client: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH4-SW5

However, I would probably implement a measure to ensure that the cache is valid and exists using the *status* property of the *applicationCache* object. If you haven't already, check the class reference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/DOMApplicationCacheClassReference/DOMApplicationCache/DOMApplicationCache.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/DOMApplicationCache

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't it seem reasonable to assume that it WILL in fact clean it, if the user needs the space for something else (music and such) - or if a certain amount of time passes without revisits?

Comment: Perhaps it will, perhaps it will not. In my opinion it doesn't seem reasonable to rely on that assumption. For the case the user didn't visit your site for the time you've updated the content: include a comment line in the manifest with a version or a simple time stamp. Every time the content of the manifest itself change, all cached content will be updated.

Comment: Thanks, Marvin, we're doing that already. The point I'm getting at, is if there are any chance of the user visiting the site, then not visiting the site for two months, then returning to the site while offline to find it unavailable (because the cache has been cleared). And does adding the app to the homescreen or similar avoid that potential issue?